# Distribution of energy in frequency bands

Tags: matlab, fft, audio, frequency, music

On my wav-file (music), I do a short-time Fourier transform (STFT). I have spectrum, which spans from $0\textrm{ Hz}$ to $f_s/2$. I took out the range between $1$ and $1000\textrm{ Hz}$, which I divided in $3$ frequency bands. My STFT is performed every $50\textrm{ ms}$ so I can see the changes over the time.

At this point I am not quite sure, if i am right or wrong. I want to get the overall performance of my frequency band every $50\textrm{ ms}$. Which means, I get $3$ values every $50\textrm{ ms}$ because I have $3$ frequency bands.

I think I need to calculate the bins of my frequency band to do that. Any idea? Btw, my code is in MATLAB.

---

I see. In my code, i did a full stft, for which i have defined a frequency vector. It looks like this:

```
f=0:1:fftlen-1;
f=f/(fftlen-1)*fs;
```

fftlen is ***4096*** and fs is ***44100***. 
 I have written it so, that i took out ***0-1000Hz*** and divided it up in 3 frequency bands, which for exmaple is a

```
lowband=(1:200);
```

and then defined a frequency vector for my lowband, otherwise it wouldn't have worked.(Maybe there is another simpler solution...)
which looks like this:

```
fL = 1:1:200;
```

I am not sure if i can see the connection behind this, but ***fs/fftlen = 10.76660156...***. This must mean that **19th bin** is about **204.56...**, which is close to my predefined frequency vector **(200Hz)** of my lower band. I got this value by doing **200/(44100/4096)**, which is **18.5759..** by rounding it off, the 19th bin. Afterwards i multiplied **19 with 10.7666...**, which is **204.56..**

If i am right then i will simply take all values from **the first bin to the 18th bin**. And make a arithmetical mean of it. Is my calculation then correct?

Answer (score 1):

To find the number of vector elements below a given frequency (in your case 200Hz) you can do:

Imagine that "f" is your vector with the frequencies, then the last position of that vector with value below 200Hz can be calculated as:

```
k = sum(f<200)
```

To better explain: f<200 will give you a vector with 0 and 1. The first elements will be 1 because they are below 200. If you sum all the 1's the you will have the position of the vector that mark the boundary.

Answer (score 0):

Frequency bins corresponding to the frequency bands could be found using the fact that each bin will represent band of $(fs/\mathbf{fft}_{pt})$.
$\mathbf{fft}_{pt}$ is the number of fft points you used for stft.

Hence you can find bins corresponding to your band of requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> If i am right then i will simply take all values from the first bin to the 18th bin. And make a arithmetical mean of it. Is my calculation then correct?

To get a overall value of some RMS you need to calculate a RMS again:
$RMS_{1...n} = \sqrt{1/n (RMS_1² + RMS_2² + ... + RMS_n²)} $

Matlab: `RMS_L = rms(frequencybins)`

However there will be an error with not meeting your desired 200 Hz band. For clearing that, I suggest to proceed as described in the [answer of arpit jain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/37034/41601) and make your bins fitting to your band (or a fraction of your band(s)).