# Making a mesh out of the parameters from a STFT

Tags: matlab, fft, time-frequency, spectrogram

I do not possess much knowledge about signal processing, so i hope to do a find an answer. 
I am reading a wav-file and then apply a fft on it.
In theory, i think i have a 3 parameters i can use. Time (length of my audio signal), frequeny and amplitude. 
i defined frequency and time like this:

```
[y,fs] = audioread('filename');
fftlen=4096;
f=0:1:fftlen-1;
f=f/(fftlen-1)*fs;

t = linspace(0,length(y)/fs,length(y))
```

Of course there are other parameters i need to define too...
But how can i define the axes for mesh? If X is time, Y=frequency and Z= Amplitude for example. I need to do it with a stft.
If necessary, i can post my whole code.

Comment: No, an FFT only has one parameter (FFT length), which directly depends on the shape of the input. I think you might be asking the wrong question ([XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)). What is it that you want to *do*?

Comment: By the way,since you and [this user](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/26185/user26185),[this user](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/26145/user26145),[this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37032/distribution-of-energy-in-frequency-bands) and [this](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/25836/user25836)share the same IP address (and hence, the same unregistered user avatar), I'd like to point out that you really should create an account when you ask multiple questions – it makes it possible for you to go back and accept answers a while after asking etc, and thus is really useful for you.

Comment: i.e when asking a lot of questions, I actually find that politeness would require you to identify yourself. That allows us to take reference to other questions of you, and might save us a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

> I am reading a wav-file and then apply a fft on it. In theory, i think i have a 3 parameters i can use. Time (length of my audio signal), frequeny and amplitude.

Given that you mention *"STFT, mesh"*, simply running a [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) on your audio signal is not going to produce what you are after. This is because, a **single** FFT, over the whole signal, returns **the same** signal in a **different representation**.

Therefore, what you are after is *many* [Short Time Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) of length shorter than the signal, applied in a *"sliding window"* way, with some overlap and their **Magnitude** Spectrum.

Eventually, what you will end up with is, a [Spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram). The output from a function that performs a spectrogram is usually a two dimensional array. One of the dimensions is related to the dimension of **Time** and the other is **Frequency**. The reason why I say *"is related to"* rather than **"is"**, is because of the "sliding window" and the fact that what you will end up with is actually a "frame index" rather than time itself. The *third dimension* is **the Magnitude** of a frequency component at some point in time (or at a given "sliding window" frame).

If you have a signal that is 1024 samples long and you do a spectrogram with 512 point FFTs and 0% overlap, you will get back a matrix that is 512x2 in dimensions.

The **spacing** between adjacent cells of the Spectrogram's output is determined by the parameters of the Spectrogram. But, in a nutshell, the spacing between **the columns** depends on the **frame overlap** and the spacing between **the rows** depends on the **Sampling Frequency**.

To turn the two dimensional output of Spectrogram to a "three dimensional" plot, all that you have to do is layout a grid of size equal to the spectrogram and modulate the dimension vertical to it by the spectrogram's magnitude.

**ALL** of this business, is done in MATLAB with two functions. [`spectrogram`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) and [`mesh`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) (or [`surf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)).

Hope this helps.