# Visualising fft-signal

Tags: matlab

Firstly, I apologize for asking several question in a short time, since it was kinda important for me. It was not my intention to be rude, so i created this account. Another thing to take into consideration, is that my english skills and my knowledge in matlab-programming or in general is limited, therefore it makes it really hard, to ask a "good" question. Simply said, it is difficult to explain my problem, but i try my best. Please consider this. 
Also, my code works at the moment, but i need to a few steps and i don't know how. PLEASE, provide an answer, solution or even an advice based on MY CODE. And i only want it to do it on matlab, since i don't know the other languages. If there is nothing, that can help me, i won't bother anymore and delete this account.

### Anyway to my question:

As you may know, i have an audiofile (music) on which i compute a STFT. I want to visualise it. See the following explanation in my code. Read the comments!

My first idea to do this way, was using the function "mesh" or something similar.

Here is my mesh-code:

```
X=1:10;
Y=1:15;
Z = [];

% Here i would define the number of time segments
% See the next following code, to understand, what i mean. 
for i = 1:length(X)

    % Here in this line, i want to compute my short fft
    %

    % number of frequencies
    for j = 1: length(Y)
        Z(j,i) = 1.0/(i*j);
    end
end

mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

This code plots me a mesh, i just wanted to know for myself, how this works. Anyway please be aware, that i am quite sure that i do not know, how the function "mesh" works to the fullest, but i think, i understood most of it. 
Another thing i need to mention is, that i am defining frequency bands in my next following code. I did this, because i noticed, i have very high amplitudes in a range from 1 - 1000Hz, which is why, i defined 3 frequency bands. It is not necessary to plot all of them, but i want to visualise at least one. Not visualising the whole frequency range from the audio signal, but only the specificially chosen band.

```
%% MATLAB
%_________________________________________
[y,fs]=audioread('dontstopmenow.wav');
% audioread = Read WAV-file
% y = Vector, which contains audio signal 
% fs = Sample Rate
% 'dontstopmenow' = WAV-file
%_________________________________________


%PARAMETER FOR STFT
%_________________________________________ 
t_seg=0.03; % Length of segment in ms

fftlen = 4096; %FFT-Points

%Defining the length of my frequency bands
f_LOW= 1:200;    % contain lower frequencies
f_MEDIUM= 201:600;  % contain medium frequencies
f_HIGH= 601:1000; % contain higher frequencies

%_______________________________________________________

segl =floor(t_seg*fs); 
% Length of segment, on which we use the fft
% "floor" rounds off the result
windowshift=segl/2; 
% size of window which goes to the next segment
window=hann(segl); 
%hann function
window=window.'; 
% From a row vector to a column vector
si=1; 
%Start index
ei=segl; 
%End index

N= length(y)/windowshift - 1;
% Number of time segements in audio signal

f1=figure;
    % New window

    f=0:1:fftlen-1;
    f=f/(fftlen-1)*fs;
    % frequency vector

    Ya=zeros(1,fftlen);
  %Plotting time segments!         
for m= 1:1:N 

    y_a = y(si:ei);
    y_a= y_a.*window;
    Ya=fft(y_a, fftlen);
    Ya=abs(Ya(1:end/2));  
      %One-sided-spectrum

      drawnow; %Updates graphical objects

    figure(f1);
    plot(f(1:end/2), 20*log10(Ya));
    %STFT __ plots the whole audio signal after a stft, every 30ms

    %% L,M,H - Bands
    subplot(3,1,1)
    y_low = Ya(f_LOW);
    plot(f_LOW,y_low);
    ylim([-20 60]);
    title('Spektrum (LOW)');
    xlabel('f(Hz)');
    ylabel('dB');
    grid on

    subplot(3,1,2)
    y_medium = Ya(f_MEDIUM);
    plot(f_MEDIUM,y_medium);
    ylim([-20 30]);
    title('Spektrum (MEDIUM)');
    xlabel('f(Hz)');
    ylabel('dB');
    grid on

    subplot(3,1,3)
    y_high = Ya(f_HIGH);
    plot(f_HIGH,y_high);
    ylim([-20 30]);
    title('Spektrum (HIGH)');
    xlabel('f(Hz)');
    ylabel('dB');
    grid on;


    si=si+windowshift; 
    % start index updated    
    ei=ei+windowshift; 
    % end index updated

end
```

Yes, i know there is a function (spectogram), which could my code shorter than this, but i prefer this method. And i am pretty sure, i need to do it this way. You see, the point is, when i do a stft every 30 ms, then i want to see this in my 3-dimensional graph(?). I want to make it visual, but i need to friggin know, how to define this 3 axes or a codeline. Bascially combining the mesh code with my stft code. If any question, please ask.

Comment: No need to apologize! Really no harm done. Your English is pretty good, too! If we don't understand something, we'll just ask :)

Comment: The problem with your post is: I don't see a clear question! *What are you specifically asking?*

Comment: And, your last paragraph again highlights that this might be a general programming matlab problem, and not a signal processing question at all.

Comment: Do you know matlab's `surf` command? It seems to be exactly what you need. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, i wasn't really sure, if it concern signal processsing or not, but i thought, i just give it a try. I imagined that audio signal also belongs to signal processing, maybe not manipulating the signal itself.

Comment: Manipulating would very much belong here, but you're really not asking a question about that! You still haven't **asked a question** (a sentence with a question mark at its end) that is precise and related to signal processing. So for now, your question is still off-topic!

Comment: As someone explained before, the output from a function that performs a spectrogram is usually a two dimensional array. One of the dimensions is related to the dimension of **Time** and the other is **Frequency**.

Comment: The reason why it  "is related to" rather than "is", is because of the "sliding window" and the fact that i will end up with is actually a "frame index" rather than time itself. The third dimension is the **Magnitude** of a frequency component at some point in time. My goal is to turn the two-dimensional output of spectogram to a "three dimensional plot" by doing a grid size which equals the size of a spectogram. This is, what actually explains my question in short.

Comment: Sry, one last comment, i was editing on it before, but it took too much time.

Comment: The words seemed familiar. The question has an answer along the lines suggested in these comments [here](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/making-a-mesh-out-of-the-parameters-from-a-stft/37224#37224). That answer can form the basis for a more complex one regarding visualisation.

Comment: Yes, it is this comment, since it actually describes my question the best or the goal i want to reach. But i don't know the necessary steps, how to go on, which is, why i am asking.